# Book for Android Hardware

Tags: android

Hi guys I am Android Application Developer and I am doing good in application development. Now I want to study about Android Hardware i.e all beneath Android OS.I tried to find some material on this but its hard for me.
Kindly refer me some good resource/BOOK.
Regards

Answer (score 3):

Android runs on a variety of hardware. I don't think you can find a book describing Android hardware.

You can examine open source hardware projects that run Android like [Beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org)

Comment: +1 @mustafa for mentioning about BeagleBoard